# ClassCastException casting error

Tags: java

I'm getting an error on my code and I really dont understand why it's happening:

```
for(Pacote<Par<String, Double>> pacote : pacotes) /snippet of code where the error occurs/
```

trying to cast it to

```
 public class Pacote <E> {

    private int capacidade;
    private ArrayList <E> pacote;

    public Pacote (int capacidade){

        pacote= new ArrayList <> (capacidade);
        this.capacidade=capacidade;
    }


  public Par (A itemA, B itemB){
      this.tipo=itemA;
      this.peso=itemB;
  }

  public A primeiro(){

      return tipo;
  }

  public B segundo () {

      return peso;
  }

}
```

public class Pacote  {

```
private int capacidade;
private ArrayList <E> pacote;

public Pacote (int capacidade){

    pacote= new ArrayList <> (capacidade);
    this.capacidade=capacidade;
}

public int getCapacidade (){

    return capacidade;
}

public int getNumItems (){

    return pacote.size();
}

public boolean estaCheio () {

    return getNumItems()<capacidade-1;
}

public boolean empacota (E item){
    if (estaCheio())
        return false;
    else { 
        pacote.add(item);
        return true;
    }
       }

public List<E> items(){

   List <E> list = pacote;

   return list;
}
```

Code around the line it is happening:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // Recebe os dados de input
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Introduza o ficheiro com a lista de items a empacotar:");
        String fich = sc.nextLine();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fich));
        System.out.println("Introduza a capacidade dos pacotes:");
        int capacidade = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());

        // Cria os pacotes
        List<Pacote<Par<String, Double>>> pacotes = 
                GestorPacotes.criaPacotes(reader, capacidade);
        reader.close();

        // Mostra a informacao dos pacotes
        System.out.println("Pacotes formados:");
        int index = 0;
        for(Pacote<Par<String, Double>> pacote : pacotes) {  /error here/
            System.out.println("Pacote " + index++ + ":");
```

And I'm getting "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: pack.Par cannot be cast to pack.Pacote", not sure why. Can someone help?

```
 public static List<Pacote<Par<String, Double>>> criaPacotes(
BufferedReader fileReader, int capacidadePacotes)
throws IOException {
        List retorno = new ArrayList <> (6);
        String s;
        while ((s=fileReader.readLine())!=null){
            retorno.add(parseItem(s));
        }
        return retorno;

    }
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the exception message tells you which classes are involved.  You're (by way of using generics) doing an illegal cast.

Comment: Please post the full stack trace for the exception so we can see what's going on.

Comment: Can you show the code around the line it is happening on. What is type is `pacotes`?

Comment: Using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880997/classcastexception-in-java-foreach-loop as a reference, it looks like you have somehow put a `Par` in `pacotes`. What does `GestorPacotes.criaPacotes()` do?

Comment: @blueygh2 thank you. but how? what is the signature? Can we see its code? It looks like it is probably returning a `List` when it should return a `List<Pacotes<Par<..>>>`

Comment: You are iterating over Pacotes as if it had declared an iterator (`implements Iterable<Pacote>` or similar), but in your code this does not seem to be the case. But that would throw a different error.

Comment: @blueygh2 `pacotes` is a `List<Pacotes<Par<...>>>` which implements `Iterable<Pacote<Par<...>>>`

Comment: Define `retorno` as `List<Pacote<Par<...>>> retorno;`

Comment: Added GestorPacotes code. I cant change the main class so something must be wrong elsewhere, I think

Comment: in `criaPacotes` your are adding something to `retorno` that is a `Par` not a `Pacote` i think.

Answer (score 1):

Your declaration of `Par` is incorrect. I suppose you want it to be an inner class, but you haven't declared it as class.

```
public Par (A itemA, B itemB){
  this.tipo=itemA;
  this.peso=itemB;
}
```

This is a constructor, but it is treated as constructor to the surrounding class, with is `Pacote`, not `Par`, so you do not actually have a *class* `Par`...